# How to use framer-motion with material-ui? (reactjs)(@material-ui/core)(framer motion)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, framer-motion

I just want to know if there is a way to use **framer-motion** with **Material-Ui**. I tried but I am not getting it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`Material-UI` has `component` prop option for this kind of requirement and should do better and more elegant approach than the wrapping-approach. Then, you can pass any props provided by `framer-motion` package to your `Material-UI` component as long as they're not conflicted (i'm not sure if any).

```
 <Button
  color="inherit"
  variant='contained'
  size="large"
  component={motion.div}
  whileHover={{
    scale: 1.2,
    transition: { duration: 0.3 }
  }}
  whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
>
  Button
</Button>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your question made me curious. I never tried the framer-motion, but was planning to learn it recently.

So I gave it a try, created a sandbox, added a Material UI and framer motion packages in it.

Just created a small button in the middle of the page using Material UI. And wrapped the button using `<motion.div>` tag, like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

function AnimatableDiv() {
  return (
    <motion.div
      className="animatable"
      whileHover={{
        scale: 1.2,
        transition: { duration: 0.3 }
      }}
      whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
    >
      <Button size="large" className="animatable">
        Button
      </Button>
    </motion.div>
  );
}

export default AnimatableDiv;
```

**And it worked!**

You might be thinking what if I use the the `motion.` directly on the `<Button>` component, like this:

```js
<motion.Button size="large" className="animatable">
  Button
</motion.Button>
```

Well, I did think of this, and I applied it as well and all the styling that Material UI applied to that button were lost! **So do not follow this approach! I repeat do not!**

Here's the link can have a look at it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sutherland-5bki9

Comment: Thank You!!
I think wrapping is the only option.

Answer (score 4):

I was also in the same situation, so after a small research, and some trial and error I wrote a small article on this, hope you guys get helped from this, and if any suggestion feels free to elaborate in the comment section.

**https://aishmn.medium.com/how-to-use-material-ui-and-framer-motion-together-6026fed96a4c**

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer's strategy is the easiest way to implement this but another strategy is to use framer-motion's wrapping.

This is my implementation with Typescript for those who might search for this problem.

`Box.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

import MuiBox, { BoxProps } from "@mui/material/Box";

const BoxComponent = React.forwardRef((props: BoxProps, ref) => (
  <MuiBox {...props} ref={ref} />
));

const Box = motion(BoxComponent);

export default Box;
```

Then use it in your component

```
import Box from "./Box";

// The motion-wrapped Mui Box now also accepts framer-motion's props
<Box
  initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
  animate={{ x: 100, rotate: [null, 10, 20], opacity: 1 }}
  whileHover={{ scale: [null, 1.5, 1.4] }}
  width={100}
  height={100}
  border="1px solid red"
/>
```

Comment: This works best with Nextjs because `component={motion.div}` throws a hydration error in Nextjs

Comment: This look like the best approach and also recommended by framer-motion doc (https://www.framer.com/motion/component/#custom-components), currently.
Mine was almost 2 years ago and might be out-dated (or may be used as work-around for quick fix or basic requirements) due to the fact that things are changing frequently in this eco-system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question so i digged a little bit in the motion doc. and i found this:
Any component can be turned into a motion component by wrapping it with the motion() function.
So i did this:

```
    import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
    import { motion } from "framer-motion";

    export default function YourComponent() {
    const TextFieldMotion = motion(TextField);
    return (
            <TextFieldMotion 
            animate={{ x: [0,20] }} 
            transition = {{ ease: "easeInOut", duration: 3 }} 
            variant="filled" 
            label="first name" 
            />
    )
     };
```

for more information: https://www.framer.com/docs/component/